# Azure IotHub - Schedule jobs on multiple devices 504 Gateway timeout

Tags: c#, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I am trying to make IotHub api request from postman for creating job to invoke direct message on multiple iot devices, I am getting **iothub-errorcode 504 Gateway timeout error**.

Following steps i performed:

1. Created IotHub account on Azure
2. Created a new device
3. Generate SAS token using this `az iot hub generate-sas-token -n <iothubName> --du <duration>`
4. Configured newly created device with C# code which is on listening mode for method named "LockDoor".

Here I attached CURL from Postman.

curl --location --request PUT 'https://myiothuburl/jobs/v2/job25?api-version=2021-04-12' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' 
--header 'Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=&sig=&skn=iothubowner' 
--header 'Host: myiothuburl' 
--header 'Content-Length: 317' 
--data-raw '{
"jobId": "job25",
"type": "scheduleDeviceMethod",
"cloudToDeviceMethod": {
"methodName": "LockDoor",
"payload": {},
"responseTimeoutInSeconds": 10
},
"queryCondition": "DeviceId IN ['myDeviceName']",
"startTime": "2022-10-11T11:51:36+0000",
"maxExecutionTimeInSeconds": 10
}'

I am following this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-jobs#jobs-to-execute-direct-methods

I am trying to make request exactly shown in above link but seems like I am making any mistake in it.
If there are any other suggestions, please feel free to share. Thanks.

Comment: I figure out this issue, when ever we use direct invoke method, it accepts string and dictionary / json, but we we run the same direct invoke method using job it only accept dictionary objects in key value form. It will not accept payload in string